# Распознавание госномеров через API и 1С

Tags: api, http, 1с

[image: JSON]1С 8.3
[image: Ответ HTTP]
[Временный файл](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/E_Y1bzKB2ufdRA)

Бухгалтерия элеватора, ред. 3

Добрый день!
Есть сервис API для бесплатного распознавания госномеров: https://data.av100.ru/docs/numberrecognize.
С его помощью решили распознавать госномера машин, которые проходят весовой контроль. То есть при взвешивании с IP-камеры сохраняется скриншот, а потом по этому скриншоту 1С должна распознать номер и вывести его.
Описание API и передача параметров вроде ясна. Однако в ответ я получаю сообщение об ошибке "Изображение для поиска не найдено". Во временном файле определенно хранятся данные картинки и передаются. Но не пойму, что не так. Может я картинку не так обрабатываю или запрос HTTP не верный? Пробовала в разной кодировке отправлять данные, но ошибка вообще не менялась, как будто картинка действительно не доходит до API. Что делать, уже без понятия. Может есть у кого-то идеи какие-нибудь. Кстати, попробовала на postman создать POST-запрос. Там все работает.
Ниже приведен код передачи картинки в API:

```
    Файл = ("gosnomer.jpg");
    ДД = Новый ДвоичныеДанные(Файл);
    Строка64 = Base64Строка(ДД);
    имяФайлаОтправки = ПолучитьимяВременногоФайла("txt");
    boundary = СтрЗаменить(Строка(Новый УникальныйИдентификатор()), "-", "");

    ЗаписьТекста = Новый ЗаписьТекста(имяФайлаОтправки, КодировкаТекста.UTF8, Символы.ПС, Ложь);
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("--" + boundary);
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""image""; filename=""photo.jpg""" + Символы.ПС);
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("");
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку(Строка64);
    ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("--" + boundary + "--");
    ЗаписьТекста.Закрыть();

    ФайлОтправки = Новый Файл(имяФайлаОтправки);
    РазмерФайлаОтправки = XMLСтрока(ФайлОтправки.Размер());

    Заголовки = Новый Соответствие();
    Заголовки.Вставить("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, boundary=" + boundary);
    Заголовки.Вставить("Content-Lenght", РазмерФайлаОтправки);

    ЗапросHTTP = Новый HTTPЗапрос("/numberrecognize.ashx?key=60b84eaf-aa77-474b-96fe-ff7e0fbdcd2a", Заголовки);
    ЗапросHTTP.УстановитьИмяФайлаТела(имяФайлаОтправки);

    Соединение = Новый HTTPСоединение("data.av100.ru",,,,,, Новый ЗащищенноеСоединениеOpenSSL());
    ОтветHTTP = Соединение.ОтправитьДляОбработки(ЗапросHTTP);
    ОтветСтрокой = ОтветHTTP.ПолучитьТелоКакСтроку();
```

Comment: см. https://forum.infostart.ru/forum15/topic216164/

Comment: Средства работы с двоичными данными - https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/5917/hdoc
Смотрите "Пример: Работа с составными (multipart) HTTP-сообщениями"

Comment: У вас `name=""image""` а в спеке параметр называется `img`. Все остальное правильно, насколько я понимаю. Попробуйте поправить. Если не получится - приложите содержимое временного файла. Также приложите содержимое `ОтветHTTP`

Comment: Сделала name=""img"". Но все равно не помогло. К вопросу прикрепила ссылку два скриншота и ссылку на содержимое временного файла.
Пробовала сделать через объединение файлов, как предоставлено по вышеуказанным ссылкам, устанавливая нужный параметр, тоже не помогло._. я чего-то не понимаю и упускаю определено. А что это?

Comment: Помню сталкивался с подобным из-за сигнатуры BOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось заставить код работать. По порядку:

1. `Content-Lenght` написано с ошибкой, правильно `Content-Length`.
2. Если используется кодировка UTF-8, то в теле запроса не должно быть сигнатуры [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).
   Это [известная проблема](https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/253878/). Так как будущее тело запроса предварительно сохраняется в файл (с кодировкой UTF-8), то в начало будет добавлен маркер из трех байт. По ссылке выше можно найти ряд решений. Есть вариант не записывать в файл, а сформировать строку и использовать метод `УстановитьТелоИзСтроки()`, в котором есть параметр <ИспользоватьBOM>. Это просто для информации. В нашем же случае, можно использовать ANSI.
3. Документация к API чуть-чуть сбивает с толку фразой "изображение с расширением .jpg". На самом деле, имеется в виду формат JPEG, а ключевой момент состоит в том, что это POST-параметр, а не файл-вложение. Поэтому из заголовка нужно убрать `filename=""photo.jpg""`, тогда сервер сможет правильно интерпретировать данные.
   `+ Символы.ПС` здесь тоже лишнее.

```1c
Файл = ("gosnomer.jpg");
ДД = Новый ДвоичныеДанные(Файл);
Строка64 = Base64Строка(ДД);
имяФайлаОтправки = ПолучитьимяВременногоФайла("txt");

boundary = СтрЗаменить(Строка(Новый УникальныйИдентификатор()), "-", "");

ЗаписьТекста = Новый ЗаписьТекста(имяФайлаОтправки, КодировкаТекста.ANSI, Символы.ПС, Ложь);
ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("--" + boundary);
ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""img""");
ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("");
ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку(Строка64);
ЗаписьТекста.ЗаписатьСтроку("--" + boundary + "--");
ЗаписьТекста.Закрыть();

ФайлОтправки = Новый Файл(имяФайлаОтправки);
РазмерФайлаОтправки = XMLСтрока(ФайлОтправки.Размер());

Заголовки = Новый Соответствие();
Заголовки.Вставить("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, boundary=" + boundary);
Заголовки.Вставить("Content-Length", РазмерФайлаОтправки);

ЗапросHTTP = Новый HTTPЗапрос("/numberrecognize.ashx?key=60b84eaf-aa77-474b-96fe-ff7e0fbdcd2a", Заголовки);
ЗапросHTTP.УстановитьИмяФайлаТела(имяФайлаОтправки);

Соединение = Новый HTTPСоединение("data.av100.ru",,,,,, Новый ЗащищенноеСоединениеOpenSSL());
ОтветHTTP = Соединение.ОтправитьДляОбработки(ЗапросHTTP);
ОтветСтрокой = ОтветHTTP.ПолучитьТелоКакСтроку();
```

Comment: Гениально. Спасибо большое! 
С Content-Length - это моя невнимательность, и даже не обращала внимание, когда скопировала о.о
Относительно других пунктов оставалось только догадываться.
Премного также благодарна за разъяснения.

Comment: @ФаинаВладимирова Я сам однажды из-за этого BOM несколько дней провозился, думал с сервером что-то. Каким-то чудом обрёл истину.